# Symfony ChoiceType ArrayCollection multiple с dataTransformer

Tags: form, symfony3

Не подтягивает selected options в форме.

Кусок **FormType**

```
->add('categories', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $this->getCategoryTree(),
            'multiple' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Корневая категория',
            'choice_label' => function(Category $category) {
                return $category->getName();
            },
            'choice_attr' => function(Category $category) {
                return ['style' => 'padding-left:' . 15 * ($category->getStep()+1) .'px;' ];
            },
            'label' => 'Привязка к категории',
            'attr' => [
                'size' => 15
            ],
            'required' => false
        ])
```

Кусок **DataTransformer**

```
public function transform($categories)
{
    if (null === $categories) {
        return '';
    }

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $ids[] = $category->getId();
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

отображение формы в templates

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                {{ form_row(form.name) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                {{ form_row(form.parent) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                {{ form_row(form.categories) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-right">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                {% if form.vars.value.parent is not empty %} {% set parentCategory = form.vars.value.parent.id %}{% else %}{% set parentCategory = null %}{% endif %}
                <a href="{{ path('user_external_service_category_tree', {
                    'id' : app.request.attributes.get('id'),
                    'category': parentCategory
                }) }}" class="btn btn-default">Отмена</a>
                {{ form_widget(form.save) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}

    </div>
 </div>
```

Как реализовать?

Comment: Кто-то поставил минус в вопрос. А ответа так и нет.

Comment: Так а где Вы задаете атрибут selected в форме?

Comment: когда использую кастомные или стандартные типы Symfony то атрибут selected работает без указания форме и его не нужно явно указывать. сейчас добавлю форму в вопрос чтобы было понятно

Comment: Вы пробовали явно select указать?

Comment: что значит явно? <select>

Comment: атрибут selected я имел ввиду

Comment: Вы угадываете или покажете свой вариант? а то у нас сейчас как пальцем в небо выглядит

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо добавить поле `data`, к котором указать индекс массива или референс сущности.

```
->add('categories', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $this->getCategoryTree(),
            'multiple' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Корневая категория',
            'choice_label' => function(Category $category) {
                return $category->getName();
            },
            'choice_attr' => function(Category $category) {
                return ['style' => 'padding-left:' . 15 * ($category->getStep()+1) .'px;' ];
            },
            'label' => 'Привязка к категории',
            'attr' => [
                'size' => 15
            ],
 'data' => 3,
            'required' => false
        ])
```

Comment: не работает такой метод. Если ставить номер колонки например 1 то идет ошибка дататрасформера. Если пытаться влепить function(){} в дата то селект не срабатывает и там же multiple = true. типа массив должен быть